# Serialize ANTLR Exceptions for GWT RPC

Tags: java, gwt, antlr, gwt-rpc, antlr3

I am using GWT-RPC to call an ANTLR grammar.
If the grammar fails, I create an object containing the errors/exceptions that were thrown by the grammar and return it to the client.

When I do this I get the exception:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.antlr.runtime.NoViableAltException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded.
```

I have found that there is an identical class with the addition of a public no argument constructor (needed for GWT-RPC serialization) in the *com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.antlr.runtime* package.

How do I convert the *org.antlr.runtime.NoViableAltException* into a *com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.antlr.runtime.NoViableAltException*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative for creating new Exceptions that can be serialized, I have made my Parser override the *emitErrorMessage* method from BaseRecognizer.

```
@members {
    @Override
    public void emitErrorMessage(String msg) {
        // The original prints to stdout.
        // You can do what you like with the message.
    }
}
```

As Tassos suggested in his answer, I did not actually need the exception, just the message from it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the exceptions themselves? I'd think not - you probably need the message or at most the stack trace. Since you're repackaging the exceptions anyway, just repack the needed strings and send those over the wire.